# Restful WebApi V2 Put Issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I cannot understand why my WebApi returns a success (200) when I Post, but doesn't return anything when I Put. Both successfully update the database.

I have attached my code for both methods.
Thanks
Paul

```
    // PUT: api/items/5
    [Route("api/items/{id:int}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutItem([FromBody] Item[] item, string updateitems)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        foreach (Item i in item)
        {
            if (updateitems.IndexOf(i.ItemId.ToString()) > 0)
            {
                db.Entry(i).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        var iStatus = StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return iStatus;
    }

    // POST: api/items
    [Route("api/items")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Item))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostItem([FromBody] Item[] item)
    {
        int itemCount = 0;
        string edititems = "";

        IHttpActionResult iStatus;
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        foreach (Item i in item)
        {
            if (!ItemExists(i.SurveyId, i.LineId))
            {
                db.Items.Add(i);
            }
            else
            {
                var id = FindItemId(i.SurveyId, i.LineId);
                edititems = edititems + ',' + id.ToString();
                i.ItemId = id;
            }
            itemCount ++;
        }
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        if (edititems.Length > 0)
        {
            IHttpActionResult result = PutItem(item, edititems).Result;
        }

        iStatus = StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return iStatus;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine, the only difference that I see is in the ResponseType attribute of the Put, you have: `[ResponseType(typeof(void))]`

Change to: `[ResponseType(typeof(item))]`

Comment: Thank you Julito. i missed that, and was really hoping that would fix it. Unfortunately I am still not getting a status back, as soon as the code hits the await db.SaveChangesAsync, the program leaves the building.

Comment: Turns out it was the Async part that was preventing the response code.